# font-awesome icons invisible on iis server no errors thrown

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, iis, fonts, font-awesome

I downloaded font-awesome locally and it seems to run fine on localhost.

When deployed to an IIS webserver the icons are completely invisible with no errors at all in the console

[image]

Ive tried setting the mime types in web.config to:

```
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".woff" /> <!-- In case IIS already has this mime type -->
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
</staticContent>
```

But still no joy

I even moved the meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

to be the first tag referenced in the `<head>` tag for the cshtml file.

Im testing using IE11.

I literally have no idea why the icons wont show as no errors are shown indicating that the font files are not being found.

### UPDATE

in regards to Jamies question i reference font-awesome in my layout file like this

```
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Home</title>
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/site.css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/script.js")
        @RenderSection("headerScripts", false)

        <link href="~/Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="~/Images/favicon.png"/>  

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="../Scripts/html5shiv.js"></script>
          <script src="../Scripts/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
```

### UPDATE 2

Okay so i replaced some of the icons with bootstraps Glyphicons and these work fine on the server. Why on earth would font-awesome not work?

Comment: Your first step should be to test in another browser to eliminate IE11 as the source of the problem.

Comment: @Shaggy Ive tried on all browsers in localhost and it seems to work fine. The webserver is a clients server so i dont have permission to install other browsers.

Comment: @jamiedanq Sorry i should have been more clear, i set it in the layout file for the application. I set the meta tag <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> to be the first tag in the <head> tag

Comment: @jamiedanq Hi jamie updated my question to show this

Comment: @Kendo I would rather reference it directly from them `<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` . However I don't see why yours `<link href="~/Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'> `shouldn't work

Comment: @jamiedanq I would love to reference the CDN it was my initial idea, unfortunately the server does not allow traffic from CDN's so i resorted to using a local version.

Comment: @Kendo this is just a guess why not add the `type ='text/css'` to your tag just for IE because it can be funny somtimes

Comment: Have you read through FontAwesome's [troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Troubleshooting)?